# Como chamar uma função dentro do Frame?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Quero chamar uma função que tenho dentro de um `iframe`. Eu programo em Ionic e queria saber como faço isso através do JavaScript ou HTML.

Dentro do JavaScript tenho uma variável (`Z = 2.5`, só um exemplo de valor mesmo) do tipo `number`.
Quero pegar essa variável e passar para a função que esta dentro de um `iframe`.

Dentro do `iframe` essa função só pega e retorna um valor.

```
function pegavalor(){
    var url = 2.5; 
    var ff = url; 
    return ff; 
}
```

Dentro do `iframe` ainda tem alguns cálculos que serão feitos com esse valor.

Como chamo esta função através do JavaScript ou HTML?

já tentei usar 
var index = window.parent; 
index.testePai();
 e não funcionou.

Comment: **Mateus**, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/323388/edit) sua pergunta e coloque um exemplo de como você esta fazendo para assim poder te ajudar, removi minha resposta novamente, mas pra poder te ajudar precisamos que você crie um [mcve].

Comment: me deparei agora com esse problema tbm, não sei como resolver!!